# How can I specify the delimiter that gspread uses when running the function import_csv to separate the fields?

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am writing a .csv file that uses `|` as the delimiter. I would like to be able to specify that when running the function `import_csv()`. How can I do this? To do this would I have to use a gspread alternative?. Tbh I just need a code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to put a CSV data to Google Spreadsheet using gspread.
- You want to put the CSV data by giving the delimiter like `|`.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet with Sheets API.

#### Issue and workaround:

When I saw the script of gspread, it seems that `import_csv(file_id, data)` puts the CSV data using Drive API. [Ref](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/514a82def82ea282304a0b980eecfc4b47c66926/gspread/client.py#L278) When Drive API is used, in the current stage, the delimiter cannot be manually set.

So, in this answer, as a workaround, I would like to propose to use the method of batchUpdate in Sheets API for achieving your goal. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "Sheet1" # Please set the sheet name you want to put the CSV data.
delimiter = "|" # Please set the delimiter.
csv = open('filename.csv', 'r').read() # Please set the CSV data.

client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
sheet = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName)
body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "pasteData": {
                "data": csv,
                "delimiter": delimiter,
                "coordinate": {
                    "sheetId": sheet.id
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
spreadsheet.batch_update(body)
```

- This script puts the CSV data to `Sheet1` in `spreadsheetId`.
- In this script, about `client`, please use it for your actual script for using gspread.

#### References:

- [import_csv(file_id, data)](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=import_csv#gspread.Client.import_csv)
- [batch_update(body)](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=batchupdate#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.batch_update)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [PasteDataRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#pastedatarequest)

### Added:

From your following reply,

> when implementing this it throws me the error: `TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable` for the variable `body`

I'm worry about that the value of `csv = open('filename.csv', 'r').read()` might be due to the reason of your current issue. So, I would like to add one more sample script. In this sample script, the CSV data is directly used in the script.

#### Sample script:

```
spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "Sheet1" # Please set the sheet name you want to put the CSV data.
delimiter = "|" # Please set the delimiter.

csv = """a1|b1|c1|d1|e1
a2|b2|c2||e2
a3|b3||d3|e3
"""

client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
sheet = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName)
body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "pasteData": {
                "data": csv,
                "delimiter": delimiter,
                "coordinate": {
                    "sheetId": sheet.id
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
spreadsheet.batch_update(body)
```

- In this sample script, the value of `csv` is put to the Spreadsheet as the delimiter of `|`.

Comment: when implementing this it throws me the error:
`TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable` for the variable `body`

Comment: @Watch With Veer Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. Because when I tested a sample CSV file, no error occurs. I apologize for this. Now, I added one more sample script. At the added sample script, the CSV data is directly used in the script. Because I'm worry about that the value of `csv = open('filename.csv', 'r').read()` might be due to the reason of your current issue. But I'm not sure about your actual CSV file. I apologize for this. Please test the added script and confirm whether the script works again.

Comment: ok thank you. The problem was, i was encoding the csv file like so `csv = open ('filename.csv, 'r').read().encode('utf-8').`

Comment: @Watch With Veer Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying and this current situation, I cannot understand whether your issue was resolved. Can I ask you about this?

Comment: @Watch With Veer Thank you for quick reply. I'm glad your issue was resolved.